# JsonLd does not work in production NextJs 13 SSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

i have dynamic page:

```
/product/[prod]/page.tsx
```

this is code in page:

```
import { ProductJson } from "./productJson";
import ProductJsonSeo from "./ProductJsonSeo";

export async function generateMetadata({
  params,
}: {
  params: { prod: string; attri: string; page?: number };
}): Promise<Metadata> {
  const product = await getProductData(params);
  const prod = product.data.product;
  const meta = MetaGenerate(
    prod.prod_seo_title,
    prod.prod_seo_description,
    `/product/${ConvertLink(prod.prod_url)}`,
    prod.prod_seo_image,
    true
  );
  return meta;
}

const ProductPage = async ({
  params,
}: {
  params: { prod: string; attri: string; page?: number };
}) => {
  const prods = getProductData(params);
  const listProd = getListProductData();
  const [product, products] = await Promise.all([prods, listProd]);
  const data = product.data;
  const ProdJson = ProductJson(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <ProductJsonSeo ProdJson={ProdJson} />
      <ProductScreen product={product} />
      <ProductList
        data={products?.data}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductPage;
```

this is getProduct:

```
import { ProductNameGetRoute } from "@/components/api";

export async function getProductData(params: {
  prod: string;
  attri: string;
  page?: number;
}) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://www.sample.com/${ProductNameGetRoute(params)}`
  );
  return await res.json();
}
```

I get Schema from "ProductJson", and its working!

and this is code in ProductJsonSeo:

```
import Script from "next/script";
import React from "react";

const ProductJsonSeo = ({ProdJson}: any) => {
  return (
      <section>
        <Script
          id="product"
          type="application/ld+json"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(ProdJson) }}
        />
      </section>
  );
};

export default ProductJsonSeo;
```

my problem is in production Json LD. In localhost, everything is working! but in production is not work. When I test in Google Schema, I do not have the result. Does anyone know what I mistake?